# Icons missing in gnome-shell, nautilus, totem

Tags: gnome, nautilus, icons

Last night when I reboot my system, I see that a lot of icons are missing. In gnome shell I don't have anymore the icon for the sound but I can still click on the space.

I have the relative same issue in nautilus, the previous and next button are missing. I tried to change my DE for Unity or Xfce but the result is similar, many icons missing (but still click-able).

I searched for answers, I tried some commands written in an archlinux forum like "gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/gnome/"  but no luck.

Does anyone have ever encountered this issue with Ubuntu? (12.10)

edit: I read that for arch, in order to repair icons, you must reinstall librsvg. Should I resinstall librsvg2-* ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you changed the icon theme?

Comment: When I change the icon theme, it just changes the icons from the dock panel. I also tried to install a gnome-shell theme to maybe get new icons but it did not work.

Comment: Same problem here. I've reinstalled librsvg2 but nothing has changed

Comment: Also have been experiencing this, but haven't tried any fixes (didn't even know where to start).

EDIT:  In case it gets asked, I have not changed a single thing on my system aside from installing the updates that Software Updater has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue (Ubuntu 12.10 - Gnome desktop) after updating librsvg packages to 2.36.3-0ubuntu1.1.

Downgrading them manually to 2.36.2-0ubuntu1 fixed the issue. You need to downgrade librsvg and librsvg-common.

Hope this helps,